# Recipient Email Formatting

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to change the formatting in the Docusign recipient email body. Does anyone know what code this field will accept or has anyone else successfully changed the formatting for the email message that goes to each recipient of an envelope? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The EmailBlurb parameter controls the message to the recipient. Basic HTML is allowed in that field, but may not be enabled for your account in particular.

Try adding html formatting to your EmailBlurb. If that doesn't come through as properly formatted, open a case with [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/) and request `Allow HTML input in the API` be enabled on your account.